# AAD implementation reply url

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to integrate my application with AAD authentication but the replyurls which i am configuring in the AAD application is

```
https://www.example1.com/abc/account/login.aspx
```

but when i am coming back after authentication i am getting redirected to

```
https://www.example1.com/
```

Only and my request is coming as authenticated but i want user to redirect to full url which i have configured.

I have tried sending RedirectUri at the time of app configuration in startup class as same as  https://www.example1.com/abc/account/login.aspx  that time user is redirect to this url but that time request is not getting authenticated

any one knows how i will achieve this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Reply URL is where the token would send to . It means that it is a endpoint 
which signs in users for that provider. But after signing in, the user will be redirect to the Homepage(Sign-on) URL.

For your scenario, you can change the Home page (Sign-on)URL in both AAD Application  and your APP config file to the URL which you want to use.

Comment: Can i have multiple URL as sign on url in AAD?

Comment: Hi @Liquid , AFAIK, I'm afraid of that you can only have one Sign on URL in AAD.

Comment: Yang thanks for the reply but is there any way where i can achieve this because my application is going to have different Sign-On URL Example :  1. https://www.example1.com/abc   
2. https://www.example1.com/pqr
3. https://www.example1.com/mno

Comment: @Liquid , You can add these URLs which under one sub domain to Reply urls. With this, the token will be sent to these urls.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) for detailed instructions on how to set up these configurations. Like Wayne said, you need to make sure that the home page URL is matched to whatever site you want the users to be redirected to after login. Then make sure that the reply URL and the RedirectURI are matching.